# Scikit-learn GridSearchCV fails to fit EM model with silhouette_score due to cryptic TypeError

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

The following code results in: `TypeError: __call__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)`.

I've instantiated a cluster classifier and a created scoring method appropriate for clustering. I've provided a simple dataset for fitting and a dictionary of parameters for the grid search. I'm having a very hard time seeing where I have an error and the traceback is fairly unhelpful.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score, make_scorer

parameters = {'n_components': range(1, 6), 'covariance_type': ['full', 'tied', 'diag', 'spherical']}

silhouette_scorer = make_scorer(silhouette_score)

gm = GaussianMixture()
clusterer = GridSearchCV(gm, parameters, scoring=silhouette_scorer)
clusterer.fit(data)
```

The traceback is cryptic and as far as I can tell I am following the syntax and workflow described in the sklearn documentation for [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.get_params) exactly. What might I be doing wrong here that would result in this error?

Here are the contents of data:

```
     Dimension 1  Dimension 2
0     -0.837489    -1.076500
1      1.746697     0.193893
2     -0.141929    -2.772168
3     -2.809583    -3.645926
4     -2.070939    -2.485348
..           ...          ...
401    -0.477716    -0.347241
402     0.742407     0.005890
403    -2.152810     5.385891
404    -0.074108    -1.691082
405     0.555363    -0.002872
416    -1.597249    -0.804744
```

Here are the last few lines of the traceback:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.pyc in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    258     else:
    259         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 260         test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    261         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    262         if return_train_score:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.pyc in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    284     """Compute the score of an estimator on a given test set."""
    285     if y_test is None:
--> 286         score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    287     else:
    288         score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)

TypeError: __call__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Look at this! I am not sure it would help though! https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4301

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem... Were you able to figure out how to use `silhouette_score` with `GridSearchCV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the thing is, you are using wrong function as a parameter to `make_scorer`. The [documentation for `make_scorer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) says:

> **score_func** - Score function (or loss function) with signature score_func(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs)

And you are passing `silhouette_score` into it which has a [signature](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) `(X, labels, metric='euclidean' ...)` which obviously doesn't match with the requirement of `make_scorer`, hence the error.

Try changing that to some other metric to resolve the error.